# Optimal numbering of rows in subgroups in MySQL InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

I need to reduce the number of entries per user in a table, leaving only the latest ones (say 10) for each user. It requires numbering of entries in a subgroup (defined by `user_id`) what is quite a tricky task in in MySQL. I tried something like this:

```
SET
    @prev_user := '',
    @counter := 0
;

INSERT tmp_table_ordered
SELECT
    @counter := CASE WHEN @prev_user = user_id THEN @counter + 1 ELSE 1 END AS counter,
    @prev_user := user_id AS prev_user,
    entry_id, timestamp, user_id, field_1, field_2
FROM table
ORDER BY user_id, timestamp DESC
;
```

It worked pretty well with MyISAM (~20 sec) on some testing table (~2 mln records), but when I switched to InnoDB the execution time grew by an order of magnitude (~6 min). I tried dabbling with indexes but it only lengthed the task. Is this code suboptimal? Is it possible to solve the task better?

Edited:

I was so sure it's the handling of variables that slows down the query I havn't even tested that. To my surprise it's not the variables what slowed down the query. It's not even the select that is slow, it is however the insertion of an InnoDB table that takes a lot of time! If only the target table type is MyIsam the insertion time is quick again.

Edited again:

The original table is like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
  `entry_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field_1` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `field_2` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii COLLATE=ascii_bin;
```

The temporary table is created like:

```
CREATE TABLE `tmp_table_ordered` LIKE `table`;
```

Comment: Try running just the SELECT (with the variables removed) and see how that goes.  If it's still slow, post the CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN results.

Comment: I made some testing and the result is written above: it's not the select that's slow, it's the insert. And the variables and all the numbering doesn't matter...

Comment: Ah, progress.  How about showing the CREATE TABLE output?

Comment: Added above. And yeah, a kind of progress, I can even change the type of the temporary table into MyIsam before insertion and it works well, but I wouldn't call it an elegant solution. Not to mention the problem is going to reappear again and again this way.

Comment: The table looks fine.  Assuming the two engines are using the same disks, I'd suggest you start looking at the tuning.  There are unfortunately 10,000 [params for innodb](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html)...

Comment: Any time you think you need to "renumber" rows, you should seriously reconsider why that is. You're probably making bad assumptions about the sequential nature of IDs which will only hurt you in the long run.